# Php string extraction and manipulation

Tags: php, string

I have problem here we I would like to add on the integer part of a serial number. Say I read as `JK001256`. Thus I can use substring to remove the first 2 char and the rest 6 as numerics. The problem I want to add to the number say 50 means it starts from `JK001256` to `JK0012306`. If I extra the numeric it get 1256 and lose the 00. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: YEs I tried substring so far but I loose the leading 00 because when I run my for loop I loose the 00 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$serial = 'JK001256';
sscanf($serial, 'JK%d', $serial_no);
$new_serial = sprintf('JK%06d', $serial_no + 50);
var_dump($new_serial); // string(8) "JK001306"
```

Working demo: http://codepad.org/jbBnofUh

Any 2-chars prefix:

```
$serial = 'JK001256';
sscanf($serial, '%2s%6d', $serial_prefix, $serial_no);
$new_serial = sprintf('%s%06d', $serial_prefix, $serial_no + 50);
var_dump($new_serial); // string(8) "JK001306"
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/aE0Htgyh

Any non-digit prefix:

```
$serial = 'JK001256';
sscanf($serial, '%[^0123456789]%6d', $serial_prefix, $serial_no);
$new_serial = sprintf('%s%06d', $serial_prefix, $serial_no + 50);
var_dump($new_serial); // string(8) "JK001306"
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/aQksxJjU

Any non-digit prefix & unspecified digits length:

```
$serial = 'JK001256';
sscanf($serial, '%[^0123456789]%s', $serial_prefix, $serial_no);
$new_serial = sprintf('%s%0' . strlen($serial_no) . 'd', $serial_prefix, intval($serial_no) + 50);
var_dump($new_serial); // string(8) "JK001306"
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/fyYskTWP

Comment: It really good working. Only problem now I must put the sscanf($serial, 'JK%d', $serial_no); . Can I just scan for any character infront?

Comment: sscanf($serial, '%s%d',$ac1, $serial_no);
$new_serial = sprintf('%s%06d',$ac1, $serial_no + 50);. I tried this to extract the character and integer separately but its not working

Comment: @user2711681 You can't just use `sscanf` with no static parts and expect `%s` to just match the first two characters. Sounds like you want `preg_match` instead

Comment: If your serial prefix will always be 2 chars, you can use `sscanf($serial, '%2s%6d', $serial_prefix, $serial_no);` then `sprintf('%s%06d', $serial_prefix, $serial_no + 50);`.

Comment: @PauloFreitas yes I already tried it works great man. But in future if if I am not sure but I would like to extract the char n integer separately is that possible or we must know some format upfront ?

Comment: @user2711681 I've added one more version which extract both non-digit and digit parts of serial string. :)

Comment: @Paulo its great for future use and for other to refer too. Thank you and marked as the answer.

Comment: For the any non digit prefix but digit must be 6 is it ? Can that be known dynamically ?

Comment: @user2711681 You're welcome! :) Yes, it can also use N digits, but for that it need some tweaks, I'll add one example for that too.

Comment: @THank you very much its great

Comment: @PauloFreitas I got one question for the dynamic version why you put this way %[^0123456789]%s' why not the %s first but then when I tried %s first its messed up.

Comment: @user2711681 'Cause `%s` in the beginning will expand to all the string, no matter what you put after that. I've used `%[^0123456789]` to catch all chars until a digit is found. Then the `%s` part will catch all the digits as string (and not integer), cause we need to further know the digits part length. :)

Comment: @PauloFreitas sorry a bit confuse here %[^0123456789] you are catching all non digit first right? There after whatever behind is considered as the digit(in terms of a string of char) ? So incase there is like this J000J2222. Then what this code suppose to do ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40787/discussion-between-paulo-freitas-and-user2711681)

Comment: @PauloFreitas sorry I missed your invitivation.

Comment: @user2711681 Just follow here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40787/discussion-between-paulo-freitas-and-user2711681 I moved discussion to chat to avoid extended discussion here.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stringVersionWithLeadingZeroes = sprintf('%06d', $numericPart)
```

http://php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php

### Update

In order to provide something complete, try this

```
if (!preg_match('/^([A-Z]{2})(\d{6})$/', $serial, $parts)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid serial number');
}

$newSerial = sprintf('%s%06d', $parts[1], (int) $parts[2] + 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$last_part = substr("JK001256", -2); // 56
$first_part = substr("JK001256",0, -2); // JK0012

$sum = $last_part + 50;

$new_string = $first_part.$sum; // JK0012306;
```

**I dont know if its the best way to do it, but it should work**

Comment: The problem is not necessary to be two 00 it can be more or less? How to solve that

Comment: This doesn't work; it produces `JK0012106`.  Concatenating strings will never work if the most significant digit in the last part changes (e.g., 56 to 106).

Comment: use a variable instead of -2 ?

Comment: I need to generate a running number say if its JK000999 then the number be should be autotmatically JK001000. How to generate this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
<?php
$value1 = substr("JK001256",2, 6);
$first = substr("JK001256",0, 2);
$index = 50;
for($i=0;$i<=$index;$i++)
{
$value2 = $value1 + $i;
$new_index[] = $first."".str_pad($value2, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

}
print_r($new_index);
?>
```

http://codepad.org/CAlJRkJ4

Comment: How best to extract the number first is by using this $first_part = substr("JK001256",0, -2); and the rest convert into int and then keep adding them with the padding is it ?

Comment: updated answer, check it